# how could I down the SDK of Extjs 7

Tags: extjs

description:when I create a formPanel,the console gives me an err:http://localhost:1841/ext/packages/core/src/field/Email.js?_dc=1599031706496 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). so I look up my app Items, there is no file of "Email.js", I think I shoud import the file to my app context,where shoud I get the Email.js  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AGs2.png)

question: I can't find the estjs's SDK of version 7 ,but the cmd.how could I down the SDK 7

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.formpanel",{
extend:Ext.form.Panel,
xtype: 'formpanel',
renderTo: document.body,

buttons: {
    submit: 'onSubmit'
},

requires:[
    "Ext.field.Email"
],
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    label: 'Name'
}, {
    xtype: 'emailfield',
    name: 'email',
    label: 'Email'
}, {
    xtype: 'passwordfield',
    name: 'password',
    label: 'Password'
}]
```

});

Comment: there is no sdk in the offical site

Comment: There is sdk on official site : https://www.sencha.com/legal/gpl/
Did you use the correct toolkit ? `Email` field is available only in Modern.

Comment: @norbeq in classic you can use textfield and add the validator Ext.data.validator.Email